# Can I overwrite same cookie text file?

Tags: javascript, cookies

I have created a JavaScript cookie for storing the URL of the last 3 visited pages in Sharepoint. It is working correctly on .NET websites and creating **one** cookie text (cookie) file at `C:\Documents and Settings\[user-name]\Cookies`.

But for Sharepoint Portal, the links are sites and different pages. It is creating different cookie (text) file for different sites inside `C:\Documents and Settings\[user-name]\Cookies` when I try to visit different link. This situation creating same name-value pair for each site and giving me wrong result.

How can I overwrite the same cookie text file?

Answer (score 1):

Cookies are linked to a domain name, including (by default) subdomain. When creating the cookie, you can specify the domain name that it should be associated with. This is to ensure that (for instance) a page from `aaa.example.com` and a page from `bbb.example.com` can both set and read cookies for `example.com`. [More here.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie#Cookie_attributes) (You can't just set any domain name, it has to be a subset of the one the response came from. E.g., from `aaa.example.com` you can say the cookie is for `example.com` but not `google.com` because the response has nothing to do with `google.com`.)

If you want to use the same cookie on pages from unrelated domains, you'll have to set the cookie as a *third-party* cookie via an image or similar. More in [a different section](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie#Third-party_cookies) of that same article.

Comment: Thanks for reply T J. My problem is it creating different files for one portal on different links so  I am not able to overwrite name-value rather than it is creating new cookie text file some links.Can I control/force this at javascript code level so that it will take same file for whole portal.

Thanks

Comment: @Ashar: I'm sorry, I don't think I understand. Can you explain further?